# Why a state is exiting while transitioning to one of its sub-states?

Tags: spring-statemachine

I am trying to implement a state machine with nested states (as linked below) using Spring Statemachine (version 2.1.3).

[Aimed state machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7zbl.png)

In the code below, I assume `stateMachineDepth3` corresponds to that machine

```java
package de.iotiq.test.statemachine;

import org.springframework.statemachine.StateContext;
import org.springframework.statemachine.StateMachine;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.StateMachineBuilder;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineStateConfigurer;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineTransitionConfigurer;
import org.springframework.statemachine.guard.Guard;
import org.springframework.statemachine.listener.StateMachineListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.statemachine.state.State;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StateMachine<States, String> stateMachineDepth2;
        StateMachine<States, String> stateMachineDepth3;

        StateMachineBuilder.Builder<States, String> builder2 = StateMachineBuilder.builder();
        StateMachineBuilder.Builder<States, String> builder3 = StateMachineBuilder.builder();

        configureL2(builder2.configureStates(), null);
        configureL2(builder2.configureTransitions());

        configureL1(builder3.configureStates());
        configureL1(builder3.configureTransitions());

        stateMachineDepth2 = builder2.build();
        stateMachineDepth3 = builder3.build();

        stateMachineDepth2.addStateListener(new StateMachineListenerAdapter<States, String>() {

            @Override
            public void stateEntered(State<States, String> state) {
                System.out.println("State (D2) -> " + state.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public void stateExited(State<States, String> state) {
                System.out.println("State (D2) <- " + state.getId());
            }
        });

        stateMachineDepth3.addStateListener(new StateMachineListenerAdapter<States, String>() {

            @Override
            public void stateEntered(State<States, String> state) {
                System.out.println("State (D3) -> " + state.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public void stateExited(State<States, String> state) {
                System.out.println("State (D3) <- " + state.getId());
            }
        });

        stateMachineDepth2.start();
        stateMachineDepth3.start();
    }

    private static void configureL1(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, String> states) throws Exception {
        states
            .withStates()
                .initial(States.S1)
                .state(States.S1)
                .state(States.S2)
        ;

        configureL2(states, States.S2);
    }

    private static void configureL2(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, String> states, States parent) throws Exception {
        states
            .withStates()
                .parent(parent)
                .initial(States.S2a)
                .state(States.S2a)
                .state(States.S2b)
        ;

        configureL3(states);
    }

    private static void configureL3(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, String> states) throws Exception {
        states
            .withStates()
                .parent(States.S2b)
                .initial(States.S2b1)
                .state(States.S2b1)
                .choice(States.S2b2)
                .state(States.S2b2)
                .state(States.S2b3)
                .state(States.S2b4)
                .state(States.S2b5)
        ;
    }

    private static void configureL1(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States, String> transitions) throws Exception {
        transitions
            .withExternal()
                .source(States.S1)
                .target(States.S2)
        ;

        configureL2(transitions);
    }

    private static void configureL2(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States, String> transitions) throws Exception {
        transitions
            .withExternal()
                .source(States.S2a)
                .target(States.S2b)
        ;

        configureL3(transitions);
    }

    private static void configureL3(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States, String> transitions) throws Exception {
        transitions
            .withExternal()
                .source(States.S2b1)
                .target(States.S2b2)
                .and()
            .withChoice()
                .source(States.S2b2)
                .first(States.S2b3, decide())
                .last(States.S2b4)
                .and()
            .withExternal()
                .source(States.S2b3)
                .target(States.S2b5)
                .and()
            .withExternal()
                .source(States.S2b4)
                .target(States.S2b5)
        ;
    }

    private static Guard<States, String> decide() {
        return new Guard<States, String>() {

            public boolean evaluate(StateContext<States, String> context) {

                System.out.println("eveluating...");

                return false;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

when I start it with `stateMachineDepth3.start();` I get the following output

```
State (D3) -> S1
State (D3) <- S1
State (D3) -> S2
State (D3) -> S2a
State (D3) <- S2a
State (D3) -> S2b
State (D3) -> S2b1
eveluating...
State (D3) <- S2b1
State (D3) <- S2b
State (D3) -> S2b4
State (D3) <- S2b4
State (D3) -> S2b5
```

As it can be seen from the output, while transitioning from `S2b1` to `S2b4`, it is exiting `S2b` which should't be the case.

For a state machine with a depth of 2 as in `stateMachineDepth2`, which consists of `S2` internals, it looks like transitions are as expected. The output is like below:

```
State (D2) -> S2a
State (D2) <- S2a
State (D2) -> S2b
State (D2) -> S2b1
eveluating...
State (D2) <- S2b1
State (D2) -> S2b4
State (D2) <- S2b4
State (D2) -> S2b5
```

Can you see something wrong about my statemachine implementation?

Answer (score 0):

dont know for sure, but refering the document https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/#quick-example ( External versus Local Transitions sub section has few details)

possibly you should use the local transition 
Here is the extract from the documentation 
**"In most cases, external and local transitions are functionally equivalent, except in cases where the transition happens between super and sub states. Local transitions do not cause exit and entry to a source state if the target state is a substate of a source state. Conversely, local transitions do not cause exit and entry to a target state if the target is a superstate of a source state. The following image shows the difference between local and external transitions with very simplistic super and sub states"**